# CSS Selector for Child Followed by Last Parent of Type

Tags: html, css

I want to target a child class that is following a parent class, but only its most immediate parent. In the code below the `.bar-on element` under the `.nested-parent` element has its visibility shown because of the very first `.foo-on`, but I only want the second `.foo-off` class to be affecting those children.

```
<style>
    .foo-on .bar-on {visibility: visible;}
    .foo-on .bar-off {visibility: hidden;}
    .foo-off .bar-off {visibility: visible;}
    .foo-off .bar-on {visibility: hidden;}
</style>

<div class="foo-off">
    <div class="bar-on">Hidden</div>
    <div class="bar-off">Visible</div>
    <div class="foo-on">
        <div class="nested-parent">
            <div class="bar-on">Visible</div>
            <div class="bar-off">Hidden</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can sort of solve this by using the direct descendant selector `.foo-on > .bar-on`, but that makes it so nested elements (the ones under the nested-parent class) aren't affected at all because they aren't direct children of `.foo-off`.

Am I missing some sort of complex selector that can select only children under a specific class but only by their closest parent? Or is this just not possible in CSS alone?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/oyLf6sm1/

Comment: Can you simplify your question, theory seems complex here.

Comment: while there are ways to solve this, by adding classes or using the markup to your advantage for example, there's no way of selecting the parent element in css. You may have to resort to javascript, unless you are able to modify markup.

Comment: In a nutshell I have an on and a off class. I want the children of those classes to be affected by their closest parent. In my example the first foo-off class is affecting the child classes under the second foo-on even though I want those only to be affected by the closest foo-on class.

Comment: @Chris I don't want to select the parent class. I only want to select the child classes.

Comment: @ryandlf, indeed. but in relation to the last parent right?

Comment: Yes, in relation to the child's closest parent. In my example the second set of bar classes are affected by the first foo parent, but I only want the second foo class to affect its children.

Comment: @ryandlf, you're probably better of using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Tried `>` selector.?? Try this.

```
.foo-on > .bar-on {visibility: visible;}
.foo-on > .bar-off {visibility: hidden;}
.foo-off > .bar-off {visibility: visible;}
.foo-off > .bar-on {visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: That's the solution I am using now, but it means I can't have classes nested under one of the parent classes.

Comment: Unfortunately that still does not work. All elements that contain hidden should not be shown.

Comment: Ok then your in your html `.bar-off` says Hidden, but you have written css as .foo-off .bar-off { visibility: visible }. then try this https://jsfiddle.net/wxoba0tx/1/

Comment: Sorry I was wrong @ryandlf https://jsfiddle.net/wxoba0tx/2/ actually, this work. shows both visible

Answer (score 0):

If you want the nested div's inside 'nested-parent' to be that way you need to make an extra style for it such as:

```
.nested-parent .bar-on{ visibility: hidden; }
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
.nested-parent:first-child{ visibility: hidden; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always so simple. The nested-parent class is really only their to show that I can't simply use a direct descendant selector. Sometimes the child classes are buried deeper.